# Maximal monotone functional

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Given a bounded  domain $\Omega$  $h:W^{1,p}(\Omega)\rightarrow W^{1,p}(\Omega)^*$ defined by
$$ h(u)=\int_{\Omega}|Du|^{p-2}(Du,Dh)_{\mathbb{R}^N}dz$$ why  is it  continuous and maximal monotone ?

Comment: because it is the subgradient of a convex and continuous function

Comment: How can we show it is continuous

Comment: Continuity follows from Hölder's inequality.